# Function that substracts a certain number every second on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been wondering if there is a way to create a function that subtracts one number from another but only at a given amount of time. I have read the time library, but I am still trying to figure it out. For example:

```
def TimeFunction:
  t = 60
  #What should I need to put here so for every second that passes, it subtracts 1?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are literally asking for:

```py
import time

def TimeFunction():
    t = 60
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
```

Although this is not very satisfying, because your program blocks on `sleep()` and nothing else would be able to see the value of `t`.

Do you want to modify your question now and ask for something slightly different?

Comment: I wanted to use this as some kind of simple timer, because later I would be displaying that on screen with the ```screen.blit()```.  I have already prepared the code of the game, should I post it here?

Comment: You should look into the timers provided by the GUI framework you are using. There is usually something that allows one of your functions to be called after a defined time period.

Comment: I will have a look then.

Comment: Nevermind. I have adapted it to my code and now it works. Thank you.